# IIS 8.5 URL rewrite to catch users without a client cert

Tags: iis, client-certificates, iis-8.5

I hope this makes sense. I'm trying to write a global rewrite rule in IIS that will abort a request if a client cert isn't presented to the IIS(rather than giving a 403 error). I've come across the cert_flags option, but I can't quite figure out what I'm supposed to put in for the condition. Has anyone done this before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still relevant, but I recently ran into this, so I figured I'd toss my solution out there.

I took inspiration from this solution for Apache https://serverfault.com/questions/411858/allowing-users-in-from-an-ip-address-without-certificate-client-authentication.

There were two things I did to make this work.  The first was to change IIS to "accept" client certificates instead of making it "require" them, while still requiring an SSL connection.  The second was to add an extra rewrite rule that processes all incoming URLs and aborts the request if it matches the condition:

- {CERT_FLAGS} Does not match pattern ^1$

CERT_FLAGS should be one if the certificate is valid as per the descriptions from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602%28v=vs.90%29.aspx and the description of how microsoft does flags https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd304685.aspx.

My web.config for that rule looked basically like:

```
<rule name="Bad Certs" enabled="true" stopProcessing="false">
    <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{CERT_FLAGS}" pattern="^1$" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
    <action type="AbortRequest" />
</rule>
```